# Set the application name for Craft in New Relic

Tags: config, newrelic

Like many of you, we've started to use New Relic to deep dive into performance of our websites.

Right now, we have a client's production server that has a version of Craft, ExpressionEngine and Wordpress.

Right now WP and Craft get lumped together as a 'PHP application'. Is there any config setting to allow us to set 'Craft CMS' as a thing to differentiate?

We've been able to do this with EE.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This method uses New Relic's PHP API, rather than php.ini, and is working well for me. It seems to be catching everything that I need to monitor. Any applications I've not done this for remain in the default application.

Just stick this in Craft's index.php file:

```
if (extension_loaded('newrelic')) {
    newrelic_set_appname('NAME OF SITE');
}
```

I haven't tried it with ExpressionEngine or Wordpress, but the principle would be the same?

Answer (score 1):

Looks like this [can be done](https://docs.newrelic.com/docs/apm/new-relic-apm/maintenance/renaming-applications#php) with a `php.ini` file in Craft's public HTML folder.

Although, we should be able to call an `ini_set` for it in Craft itself.  If you want to hit up support@buildwithcraft.com, I'll give you a file that you can test with.